# How to access variable sent from Rails 4 controller in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `@coords` variable:

```html
#maps controller
 def index
    @coords = Map.all
  end
```

Inside index.html.erb, I have:

```html
<%= content_tag 'div', id: 'coords', data: @coords.to_json do %>

<% end %>
```

How my content_tag looks like after rendering HTML page:

```html
[{"id":1,"vibration_level":456,"lat":"71.45543","lon":"53.43424","time_sent":"1994-05-20T00:00:00.000Z","created_at":"2015-06-13T06:53:30.789Z","updated_at":"2015-06-13T06:53:30.789Z"} ]
```

How can I access it from a JavaScript file.

Comment: Are you rendering it as text in a `div`?  You need to render it in a `script` tag and assign it to a variable.  Then any JavaScript code on the page can reference that variable.

Comment: @David, I tried that too, the problem is that my external script is loaded first, so it cant see my variable defined in html page.

Comment: Then load the scripts in the correct order.  No language can reference a value before it's been defined, this isn't specific to Rails and/or JS.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem. This gem is for sending data from rails to your JavaScript.

You can do smth like this:

```
#map controller    
def index
  @coords = Map.all
  gon.coords = @coords.to_json
end
```

And then you can acces your variable in JS:
`gon.coords`

Comment: Personally, I think this is much better than sending an instance variable's contents as a string into a `data-` tag in the view and then hacking away with jQuery to grab the string and then parsing it back into an object. On a side note, would you happen to know if gon can send over any kind of data type? Like a function?

Comment: https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-example You can for sure pass int, array, hash, string.